# Get image src by class name in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

i am trying to get url of large image from a page

```
<ul id="etalage">
<li class=" product-image-thumbs" >
<img class="etalage_source_image_large" src="http://website.com/media/1200x1200/16235_1.jpg" title="" />
<img class="etalage_source_image_small" src="http://website.com/media/450x450/16235_1.jpg" title="" />
</li>
</ul>
```

my vba code is

```
Public Sub macro1()
Dim ie As Object
Dim name As String
  Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "RUNNING"
    URL = Selection.Value
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With ie
      .Visible = 1
      .navigate URL
      While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
      Wend
    End With
Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
    Set Doc = ie.document
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "ERROR"
    name = Trim(Doc.getElementsByClassName("product-image-thumbs")(0).innerText)
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = name
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "successful"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ie.Quit
  Loop
End Sub
```

my code giving blank cell...

also please suggest me how to run this macro faster.... i have 3000 url to work on.

> Thanks in advance

Comment: On the document, you have a leading space `" product-image-thumbs"`, but on the macro you check for `"product-image-thumbs"`

Comment: To run it faster, why don't you create the IE object only once and navigate as needed?

Comment: @PhillipBeck not working with leading space also... :(

Comment: @Sgdva not working if i create IE outside loop, any other suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comments, try to speed the code up this way (untested code). The inner-text of the `li` element is empty string becasue there is no text inside of it, there is an `image` element but no text. HTH

```
Public Sub macro1()
    Dim ie As Object
    Dim name As String
    Dim Doc As HTMLDocument

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = 1

    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "RUNNING"
        url = Selection.Value
        ie.navigate url
        While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Wend
        Set Doc = ie.document
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "ERROR"
        name = Trim(Doc.getElementsByClassName("product-image-thumbs")(0).innerText)
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = name
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "successful"
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop

    ie.Quit
End Sub
```

To get the `src` of all the `images` try using `querySelectorAll` method.

```
Dim img, imgs As IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection, i
Set imgs = Doc.querySelectorAll("li[class~='product-image-thumbs']>img")

For i = 0 To imgs.Length - 1
    Set img = imgs.item(i)
    Debug.Print img.getAttribute("src")
Next
```

See [CSS attribute selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp).

EDIT:
If there are more `img` elements inside if the `li.product-image-thumbs` element then you have more possibilities how to get the right one `img`.

- Get `img` which is placed immediately after the `li` :

`"li[class~='product-image-thumbs']+img"`

- Get `img` inside of `li` by class name :

`"li[class~='product-image-thumbs'] img[class~='etalage_source_image_small']"`

Comment: it worked, but it giving me another image url, i forget to tell i have one more image url in page source under "product-image-thumbs", it is giving me url of second image...

Comment: Edit the question and add the information you forget. I will edit the answer according to this new info.

Comment: Set img = imgs.Item(0)